# Is there a good browser based sandbox to practice TCL?

Tags: tcl

I am looking for recommendations for a browser based TCL sandbox to practice some proof of concept code.

Google search just brings up books and online courses, but I want to try out some coding, and was trying to avoid installing a TCL emulator.

Comment: I didn't know TCL was capable of anything dangerous enough to need a sandbox...

Comment: I'm just looking for a quick way to try some test code without having access to an TCL emulator.  If I knew of one, I would have an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124185/what-does-this-do-in-tcl

Comment: See [Online-IDEs](http://wiki.tcl.tk/41455) on the [Tclers Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're happy with being stuck with using 8.4.16 (which is a bit old now) then you can use [Codepad](http://codepad.org/?lang=Tcl) as that includes Tcl support among its many languages.

Comment: @Noah: Except that it wouldn't have let you answer that SO question; expansion syntax requires 8.5…

Comment: I found that out :( ... Maybe I can encourace the codepad people to update the TCL backend ...  However, this was still exactly what I wanted, so you get credit for the answer

Comment: @Noah http://ideone.com/ has Tcl 8.5.7. With argument expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want any browser based sandbox instead of just getting a tclkit (single file, no install needed, see http://www.patthoyts.tk/tclkit/) and fire up its console/repl loop and start trying?

In case anyone really needed a web based sandbox, it would be trivial to do, especially as there already is a built in SafeBase sandbox in the language so adding some simple frontend is all you need.

Comment: No, it is not as trivial as you might think. I run a publicly accessible sandbox (on IRC) that uses that mechanism, but it has still some ways to beat it. (Runtime/ressources, not the security, which is IMHO good enough)

Answer (score 1):

I use tclsh normally to try out little code snippets. You can download it from the Activestate guys. The only web-based shell that I know of is the one that comes with each OpenACS installation, however as it's a bit of a security risk making such a shell open to the public, you might have  trouble getting your hands on one. :-)

There is a site where you could quickly try out OpenACS at http://www.oacsrocks.org/ -  you just have to register and they will setup an installation on their servers, and give you admin privileges on it. Once that is up and running you just need to surf to /ds/shell.tcl and you can try out any TCL commands you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) I've made tcl code in there before.