# Parallel processing in Expect

Tags: tcl, expect

The code below works well right now; however, it's serially executed. I'd like to be able to roll through the source_list file until I get a max number of sessions and let them all complete and feed the results back to this parent script. Is that possible or would it require me to change the script I'm calling to feed back the results? I've looked at the fork command but it somewhat eludes me.

```
set source_list [lindex $argv 0]

set device_list [open $source_list r]
while {[gets $device_list ipaddress] != -1} {
spawn "./ios-upgrade.exp" 0 $ipaddress username password image-file MD5hash ftp-server
expect eof
}
close $device_list
```

Comment: Is there an easy way you can split your `source_list` file into multiple pieces in a way that makes most sense? (e.g., would `split -l` work to split your input file?)

Comment: My input file is actually just a list of IP addresses. So I'm just looping through to feed that to the script.

Comment: Do you still have a question, or has this resolved your concern?

Comment: Posted my question below your proposed answer below about the order of the arguments being passed to the called script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really need is:

```tcl
exec ./ios-upgrade.exp 0 $ipaddress username password image-file MD5hash ftp-server &
## No need for an expect statement here since you didn't spawn...
```

The `&` character at the end of `exec` backgrounds the script in the shell so your loop will not be blocked for the return code.

However, you are sending the username and password as CLI args, so they will also show up in the process table when someone does `ps auxw` or its ilk.  I would store the username / passwords in the same file with your IP address, and use:

```
exec ./ios-upgrade.exp 0 $ipaddress image-file MD5hash ftp-server &
## No need for an expect statement here since you didn't spawn...
```

After `ios-upgrade.exp` is done, have it write a file named something like `ip_4_1_12_18.out` and iterate through the directory until you have received status for all the ip addresses.

---

OP's additional information:

Turns out the missing piece of information to the above answer was to eval the variable so it was passed properly.

```
exec ./ios-upgrade.exp 0 {*}$ipaddress image-file MD5hash ftp-server &
```

*Note that `{*}` only works with TCL 8.5 and above.

Found the answer in the following: [How to add a variable amount of arguments to exec in tcl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535719/how-to-add-a-variable-amount-of-arguments-to-exec-in-tcl)

Comment: I'm trying to store the username and passwords in the same list. However the problem is it reads the entire line in and doesn't put the variables out in the right order for the called script to execute.


See the output below:


passed the following file:
192.168.1.2 testuser testpassword


spawn ssh test.txt@192.168.1.2 testuser testpassword


For whatever reason it is executing 0 image-file "result of gets" it should be executing 0 "result of gets" image-file MD5hash ftp-server

Comment: Gave me a good start. I'll be posting a follow up question in regards to the variable substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the missing piece of information to the above answer was to eval the variable so it was passed properly.

```
exec ./ios-upgrade.exp 0 {*}$ipaddress image-file MD5hash ftp-server &
```

*Note that `{*}` only works with TCL 8.5 and above.

Found the answer in the following: [How to add a variable amount of arguments to exec in tcl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535719/how-to-add-a-variable-amount-of-arguments-to-exec-in-tcl)

Comment: I am scratching my head why my answer was not selected, given what I said about eval and backgrounding the task

Comment: @MikePennington I'm looking at your posted answer below and it is 90% of what got me there but you didn't seem to mention eval or {*}. If you don't mind me editing your answer to include some of the information above to make it more complete I will gladly accept your answer.

Comment: either `exec` or `eval` should work.  I did not have access to your script, so I could not fully vet out all issues.  I included your edits in my answer.  Thank you for considering this as an option.