# Which is the correct way to pass variable params in tcl exec?

Tags: linux, tcl, parameter-passing

i work in Linux and i normally execute the following command in the shell:

```
SomeCommand <Standard params> <params of type A> <params of type B> > Out.log
```

Now i want to call this in a TCL script like so:

```
set ParamsA "-some params of type A"
set ParamsB "-some params of type B"
set AllParams "-moreStandardParams $ParamsA $ParamsB"
exec SomeCommand $AllParams > Out.log
```

i am having some hard time making this work, because no matter what i try i cant seem to make all the params visible to SomeCommand.
what is the correct way of doing this?
i am obviously new to TCL. what is the difference between "" [] {} and are there any other ways of enclosing the params? What is the rule with the white spaces pre and post parenthesis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a variable amount of arguments to exec in tcl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535719/how-to-add-a-variable-amount-of-arguments-to-exec-in-tcl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that `exec` takes a set of words as arguments and it is
getting passed only one.

I like to use a list to build up the command line.  Then for the actual `exec`, the list must be expanded into separate words.  lists have an 
advantage that when they are converted to a string (e.g. `$mylist`), the
canonicalized (string-ified, serialized) form will always convert back to
the same list.

```
set cmd mycommand
lappend cmd -param1 p1
lappend cmd -param2 p2
if { $someoption } {
  lappend cmd -param3 p3
}
lappend cmd -debug

exec {*}$cmd > $outfile
```

If you are using an older version of Tcl, you will need to use the eval statement:

```
eval exec $cmd > $outfile
```

Edit: missed the other half of your question.

Double quotes enclose a string and allow interpolation of escaped characters
and substitution of variables and commands:

```
 set cmd command
 "here is [string toupper my] $cmd\r\n"
```

Braces are similar to single quotes in algol-derived languages.  They specify a string.  No command and variable substitution is done.  Backslash interpolation is not done:

```
 {here is [string toupper my] $cmd\r\n}
```

Brackets specify that the first word is a command and should be processed
as a command.