# How to pass multi-word space-divided string value as separate arguments to the program in expect script?

Tags: expect

Suppose I have a simple `expect` script (`simple.exp`):

```
set command "ls -l somedir"
spawn $command
interact
```

Executing this script results in error because `expect` treats ls -l (whole string with spaces) as a command rather than ls as a command and -l as an option:

```
expect -f simple.exp
spawn ls -l
couldn't execute "ls -l somedir": no such file or directory
     while executing
"spawn $command"
     (file "simple.exp" line 2)
```

What I want is the behaviour similar to `bash` which processes the string first and breaks it down into distinct arguments to start the command:

```
bash -c "ls -l somedir"
```

Note that variable `command` is hardcoded in the script for simplicity. In real script it is supplied as argument (arbitrary command line string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way to make a command is to use `Tcl`'s *list* command. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set cmd [list ls -l "a b c.txt"]
if { [package vcompare $tcl_version 8.5] < 0 } {
    eval spawn -noecho $cmd
} else {
    spawn -noecho {*}$cmd
}
expect eof
```

Comment: Although I was satisfied by the answer I found first myself, I accept yours as it helped me to solve the problem in a wider cross-platform context due to various versions of TCL. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The hint to the solution is in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124185/what-does-do-in-tcl) (`expect` uses `tcl` language):

```
set command "ls -l somedir"
spawn {*}$command
interact
```

The `{*}` syntax splits the following string into its whitespace-separated words.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set command "ls"
set parameter "-la"
set prompt ":~"
spawn $command $parameter
expect $prompt
```

Comment: I've updated description to avoid assumption that the `command` is hardcoded. Therefore, you don't know what is command name and what is parameter - `command` is arbitrary command line. See also `bash` example - it parses whatever user provides.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bash string variable which is used as an argument for the expect script, you can try using lrange:

```
set command [lrange $argv x y]
```

where x and y are the start and end of the arguments inside the string variable.
For example:
If your string variable is

```
myvariable="hello how are you?"
```

and your're using it like this:

```
./shellscript $myvariable
```

then your expect script line will look like this

```
set command [lrange $argv 0 3]
```

You can use $command anywhere in your expect script. It will have whitespaces as wanted.