# TCL/Expect - exec - how to execute program with parameters

Tags: arguments, tcl, exec, command-line-arguments, expect

I am experimenting with TCL command `exec` in `tclsh` and here are my results:

```
% set show_me_dir "ls"
ls
% exec $show_me_dir
VboxSharedFolder
% set show_me_dir "ls -la"
ls -la
% exec $show_me_dir
couldn't execute "ls -la": no such file or directory
% set show_me_dir {ls -la}
ls -la
% exec $show_me_dir
couldn't execute "ls -la": no such file or directory
% ls -la
total 141
d---------+ 1 wakatana Domain Users     0 Jan 22 19:12 .
d---------+ 1 wakatana Domain Users     0 Apr 16  2014 ..
----------+ 1 wakatana Domain Users 20214 Jan 23 18:43 .bash_history
----------+ 1 wakatana Domain Users  1494 Apr 15  2014 .bash_profile
----------+ 1 wakatana Domain Users  7593 Jan 22 19:03 .bashrc
d---------+ 1 wakatana Domain Users     0 Jan 15 14:56 VboxSharedFolder
%
```

Can somebody please explain how can I execute command with arguments?

**Edit:**

The following example from [Expanding a list of parameters in Tcl and eval](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/3583_Expanding-a-list-of-parameters-in-Tcl-and-eval.html) article was big eye opener of what is going on here:

The variable `$action` is only expanded into the string `"piemiddle apple"` **AFTER** the command line has been split into its individual parameters:

```
% set action {piemiddle apple}
% set $action
can't read "piemiddle apple": no such variable
```

Result: `set` command "sees" one argument, equivalent to:

```
% set {piemiddle apple}
```

The expand operator allows you to specify that a variable is to be expanded **BEFORE** the command line is split into individual parameters:

```
% set action {piemiddle apple}
% set {*}$action
apple
```

Result: `set` command "sees" two arguments, equivalent to:

```
% set piemiddle apple
```

In earlier versions of Tcl, the eval command was the recommended alternative and it remains available today.

```
% set action {piemiddle apple}
% eval set $action
apple
```

Another examples which proves functionality of expansion operator:

```
% set {*}"name Linus"
Linus
% puts $name
Linus
%
%
% set distro Unbuntu
Unbuntu
% set {*}"linux $distro"
Unbuntu
% puts $linux
Unbuntu
%
%
```

Finally the discovery that `exec` needs command as it's first argument and first command option as it's second argument etc.

```
% exec "ls" "-la"
total 137
d---------+ 1 wakatana Domain Users     0 Jan 22 19:12 .
d---------+ 1 wakatana Domain Users     0 Apr 16  2014 ..
----------+ 1 wakatana Domain Users 20214 Jan 23 18:43 .bash_history
----------+ 1 wakatana Domain Users  1494 Apr 15  2014 .bash_profile
----------+ 1 wakatana Domain Users  7593 Jan 22 19:03 .bashrc
d---------+ 1 wakatana Domain Users     0 Jan 15 14:56 VboxSharedFolder
%
%
% exec "ls -la"
couldn't execute "ls -la": no such file or directory
```

Comment: Please take a moment to reflect on the subject of argument expansion, which was explained to you in the answers to your previous question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **safest** way to build a command for `exec` is to use Tcl's `list`. For example:

```
% set tcl_version
8.5
% set cmd [list ls -l tmp]
ls -l tmp
% eval exec $cmd
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 pynexj  staff  1176 Jan 23 23:24 file.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 pynexj  staff  1176 Jan 23 23:24 foo-1.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 pynexj  staff  1176 Jan 23 23:24 foo-2.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 pynexj  staff  1176 Jan 23 23:24 foo-3.dat
% exec {*}$cmd
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 pynexj  staff  1176 Jan 23 23:24 file.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 pynexj  staff  1176 Jan 23 23:24 foo-1.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 pynexj  staff  1176 Jan 23 23:24 foo-2.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 pynexj  staff  1176 Jan 23 23:24 foo-3.dat
%
```

Note that [{*}](http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/293) is a new syntax of Tcl 8.5 which can help reduce the uses of `eval`.

Comment: Isn't TCL list just ordinary strings where each word is separated with space? I think `set cmd [list ls -la /tmp]` and `set cmd "ls -la /tmp"` are the same.

Comment: Note that 8.4 is out of support now. We will no longer do even security patches for it. Not that we're aware of anything in it that _needs_ patches that wouldn't be better fixed by just going to 8.5 anyway. The level of compatibility between the two is mostly very high (unless you're relying on integers being a fixed width, in which case your code already isn't portable).

Comment: @WakanTanka: The are not the same. For example, just think how you can do the same thing as `set cmd [list ls -l "foo bar.txt"]` without using `list`. And `set cmd [list echo \[]`?

Comment: @whjm: e.g. by using escaping with backslash? It's a little  bit ugly syntax but it will work I suppose.

Comment: Yes by using backslash escapes we can construct valid lists. But it's not always easy and it's error prone.

Comment: @whjm: I agree, but as I said those two mentioned constructions does exactly the same thing in the end.

Comment: @WakanTanka: For this specific case, yes. But don't think you can always construct correct lists this way especially when you don't know in advance what the data would look like. :)

Answer (score 1):

As example for `ls` command you can do:

```
exec {*}ls -lsa {*}[glob *.cpp]
```

Please have a look at [What does {*} do in TCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124185/what-does-do-in-tcl/)