# how to link a program from different shell in tcl

Tags: tcltk

I was trying to build a GUI for an open source software using TCL/TK. This open source works in a different shell.

so, How do I open it (vagrant ssh) from TCL? for example "~/openthread/etc/vagrant/vagrant up" this is the path for the shell which will open up the vagrant. how do I set it into a button, for example, whenever a user presses the button, the above directory is run which brings up the vagrant shell?
can I do that in TCL/TK?

TIA for the help and suggestions.

Comment: Please, describe your environment in details. What is OS for host, guest?

Comment: I am using TCL/tk on windows with active TCL. Both the host and the guest are in windows OS. The host is in TCL shell and the guest is in vagrant shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't provide solution, but only directions

1. You can run terminal, execute command there and leave it open. ( source: https://superuser.com/a/876959)

   `cmd /K "path-to-vagrant ssh"`
2. So, you should use `exec` [Running other programs from Tcl - exec, open](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl26.html) to run  `cmd`
3. following link can be  also useful [exec - how to execute program with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095820/tcl-expect-exec-how-to-execute-program-with-parameters)